# Remove an item in list and get a new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I saw there are several topics on removing items from a list, including using `remove()`, `pop()`, and `del`. But none of these is what I am looking for, since I want to get a new list when the items are removed. For example, I want to do this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
<fill in >       # This step somehow removes the third item and get a new list b and let
b = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with `a.pop(2)`?

Comment: @barakmanos i believe it returns element and not new `list` object as OP want it.

Comment: @khelwood OP wants to create new list without the 3rd item, not without the int `3`

Comment: `b = a[:2]+a[3:]`

Comment: b=a[:];b.pop(2)  ???

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes. Your suggestion is better.

Comment: @vishes_shell: It rturns `[1,2,4,5,6]`, which is exactly what OP wants (you can precede it with `b = ` if you want to store it somewhere).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to have a new list without the third element then:

```
b = a[:2] + a[3:]
```

If you want a list without value '3':

```
b = [n for n in a if n != 3]
```

Comment: `b = a[:2] + a[3:]` it is. Thanks @Yevhen. I thought Python has something built-in function to do this, well, maybe not. But this is an excellent solution!